# Making elements inside of a div go under each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a small box where people can log in to my site, but im not the best at CSS. I want to have it like this

paragraph "username" 
input(text) 
parargraph "password"
input (password)
button(submit)

with small spaces between but I cant understand how to make them stay under each other :(

could a nice codegod help me?

CSS:

```
.login {
float: right;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
background-color: white;
}

.login p{

float: left;
margin: auto 0;
clear: both;
}
.login input{
float: left;

}
.login button{
float: 
}

.login input{
text-align: center;
}
button.loginBtn{

}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Matombrining</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/Stil.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<header class="banner">

</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href ="index.html">Hjem</a></li>
        <li><a href ="#">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href ="#">Hvorfor</a></li>
        <li><a href ="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>    
</nav>

<main class="mainContent">
    <h1>Hovedinfo</h1>
    <div class="login">
        <h1>login boks</h1>
        <p>Brukernavn</p>
        <input type="text" class="userIn" id="userIn"></input>
        <p>Passord</p>
        <input type="password" class="passIn" id="passIn"></input>

        <button type="submit" class="loginBtn" id="loginBtn">Logg inn</button>
    </div>

</main>
```

Sorry if this code looks bad, havent played around with coding for a long time hehe.. Help is very much appreciated!!!

Comment: Why are you using float in your CSS? This will prevent the elements from appearing on separate lines. Float is used to force an element to float, allowing other elements to wrap around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is (almost) default behaviour, just the input and button need to be turned in to `block` elements to have them go onto their own line. have a look at the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/kr8cyobk/

```
    <div class="login">
        <h1>login boks</h1>
        <label>Brukernavn
            <input type="text" class="userIn" id="userIn" />
        </label>
        <label>Passord
            <input type="password" class="passIn" id="passIn"></input>
        </label>

        <button type="submit" class="loginBtn" id="loginBtn">Logg inn</button>
    </div>
```

And this is all the css you need for that login form:

```
input, button {
    display: block;
}
```

Note that I took the liberty of making your inputs self closing (`<input />`) and turning those `p` tags in the semantically more correct `label`s so you have the added advantage of making them clickable, and things like screenreaders and crawlers can make more sense of your page.